# Метод для вывода данных в listView из локальной базы данных

Tags: java, android

Как правильно прописать запрос на вывод данных из базы данных SQLite?
Создала класс унаследованный от SQLiteAssetHelper:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="example.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_TABLE = "group";

//constructor
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

}
Далее класс для управления бд:

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;
Cursor c = null;

//private constructor so that object creation from outside the class is avoided
private DatabaseAccess(Context context)
{
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}
//to return the single instance  of database
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context)
{
    if(instance==null)
    {
        instance=new DatabaseAccess(context);

    }
    return instance;
}
//to open the Database
public void open()
{
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
//closing the database connection
public void close()
{
    if(db!=null)
    {
        this.db.close();
    }
}
```

}

В классе  DatabaseAccess я бы и хотела прописать метод для вывода данных в listView.
Подскажите как правильно это реализовать? предыдущие попытки не увенчались успехом.

Comment: Я попытался упростить вашу задачу максимально, и набросал вам шаблон для работы. В нем создана база данных, и данные выводятся в RecyclerView. Ничего лишнего, Самый минимум. Пример рабочий, можете скачать и посмотреть https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UPqQnGGleh3DGvXWpdKAGEUhq2hFG_Qg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать класс для работы с бд наследуясь от SQLiteOpenHelper, вот пример

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static final int VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="DataBase.db";
public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+ Product.TABLE_NAME + " ("+
            "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            Product.TITLE   + ", "+
            Product.CALROIE_PRODUCT+")");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EatItem.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}
Чтобы написать запрос, нужно получить доступ к бд

```
SQLiteDatabase mDatabase=new
                DataBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase()
```

и написать код запроса

```
 public List<Product> getProductList(){
    ArrayList<Product> productList=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor =mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from "+Product.TABLE_NAME,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Product product=new Product();
            product.setId(cursor.getString(0));
            product.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            product.setCalorieProduct(cursor.getString(2));
            productList.add(product);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();



 return productList;
};
```

Вот так я получал из бд свои продукты)
По поводу курсора советую почитать отдельно.
Ну а в конце полученные данные просто передать в адапатер ListView

Comment: Если вам нужны объекты из БД, то следует использовать ORM, типа Room. Получать данные в курсор, а потом перегонять их в какой то arraylist, занятие неблагодарное и ресурсозатратное. ListView имеет адаптер для работы с курсором напрямую, зачем эти бесполезные прослойки данных